# Sympy support for Modular groups

Tags: python, sympy, pari-gp

Does Sympy support modular groups?

I'm looking for something akin to `pari/gp`'s `Mod` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhat confusingly, the ring of integers modulo n is implemented as `GF(n)` (the notation suggesting finite fields, which these in general are not). So, 5 mod 12 would be represented by

```
>>> from sympy import GF
>>> x = GF(12)(5)
>>> print(x)
5 mod 12
>>> print(x*4)
8 mod 12
>>> print(-x)
7 mod 12
>>> print(x+10)
3 mod 12
>>> print(x**2)
1 mod 12
```

Comment: In what module is GF defined?

Comment: `from sympy import GF` works for me; a more specific import would be `from sympy.polys.domains import GF`